# A way to know the version of the build of an React App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

We are using the **create-react-app** to create our client React app.
We are deploying the app several times a week.
We'd like to version every build so we can check which version is online.

I'm thinking about adding a meta tag with the version to the index.html file.
So currently the header has:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
  <title>React App</title>
  <link href="/static/css/main.b100e6da.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

What do you think about adding a meta like this one:

```
<meta name="build-version" content="2019-10-08-15-42" />
```

With the content using the format: YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM

What do you think about this idea? Or is there another way to version every build.

If it is a good idea, can you help me with some ideas on how to do it?

Comment: you might try this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2466#issuecomment-308798289

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Bhojendra Rauniyar I got this solution:

1. Add this line to `public/index.html`:

`<meta build-version="%REACTBUILDVERSION%"/>`

2. Run this 3 commands:

```
REACTBUILDVERSION=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)-$(date +%T)
sed -i -- 's/%REACTBUILDVERSION%/'$REACTBUILDVERSION'/g' build/index.html
echo React Build Version = $REACTBUILDVERSION
```

To make it comfortable, these 3 commands can be added to the build in `package.json`:

**Original build in `package.json`**:

`"build": "react-scripts build",`

**NEW build in `package.json`**:

```
"build":
     "react-scripts build &&
      REACTBUILDVERSION=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)-$(date +%T) &&
      sed -i -- 's/%REACTBUILDVERSION%/'$REACTBUILDVERSION'/g' build/index.html &&
      echo React Build Version = $REACTBUILDVERSION",
```

After the build you can see this meta tag in the `build/index.html`:

```
<meta build-version="2019-10-16-16:31:43"/>
```

Comment: On windows I get "'REACTBUILDVERSION' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: For Windows, create a file named: change-version.sh (on the root directory of of your CRA project) and insert the code as provided on Step:2, then on build command in the package.json file, use this: "react-scripts build && change-version.sh"

Comment: I tried this, and it seems it tried to open change-version.sh in git for windows. Doesnt seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: @sammy

To do this in Windows VS Code:

`"build": "react-scripts build && powershell ./change-version.ps1",`

That's the line in package.json.

`((get-content build/index.html -Raw) -replace "%REACTBUILDVERSION%", (get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm")) | set-content -path build/index.html`

That's the contents of "change-version.ps1".

This will shove a readable date string into your build/index.html, in the format that OP asked for.

You may have to change your powershell script execution policy.

Answer (score 5):

I follow the following approach (will add git branch name in the version):

```
# First add '<!-- version: %VERSION% -->' to your public/index.html file
$ yarn run build # npm run build (if using npm)
$ VERSION=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
$ sed -i -- "s/%VERSION%/$VERSION/g" build/index.html
```

Now your `build/index.html` should contain `<!-- version: name-of-the-current-branch -->`.

[source](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2486#issuecomment-308734212)

---

To make it comfortable, you may add version command in package.json:

```
"build": "VERSION=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` && 
         react-scripts build && 
         sed -i -- 's/%VERSION%/$VERSION/g' build/index.html"
```

Now, you can simply run:

```
yarn build # or, npm run build
```

Comment: With the command: `sed -i -- "s/%VERSION%/$VERSION/g" build/index.html`

Appears this error: `sed: 1: "s/%VERSION%/feature/App ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'A'`

Comment: It's working changing double quotes with single ones:
`sed -i -- 's/%VERSION%/$VERSION/g' b`

Comment: The command is running without errors but the replace of variable `%VERSION%` don't. I'm still working on the command.

Comment: Hi, I think you are missing single quotes around $VERSION
Like this:
sed -i -- 's/%VERSION%/'$VERSION'/g' build/index.html

Answer (score 4):

You can also add a version key pair to your package.json file `"version": "1.0.0"` and then you can read it anywhere in your code as follows
`let packageJson = require('./package.json')`
then doing `packageJson.version` should give you access to the version that is set in the package.json file
 a similar thing happens when the version is placed in `app.json`